# How to update profile properties for a commerce user

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Using Sitecore Commerce 10.1

The following method updates only the default profile properties(like phone, name).
It is not updating the custom properties.
The custom properties are available for the user, when I check in debug.

No errors. The update isn't happening, when I check in biz tools.

```
public void UpdateProfileProperty(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    CustomerServiceProvider customerProvider = new CustomerServiceProvider();    
    GetUserRequest userRequest = new GetUserRequest("MyDomain\\myemail.com");
    GetUserResult result = userRequest != null ? customerServiceProvider.GetUser(userRequest) : null;
    CommerceUser user = result.CommerceUser;
    
    if (commerceUser != null)
    {
       commerceUser.SetPropertyValue(propertyName, propertyValue);
       // Update the user
       var updateRequest = new UpdateUserRequest(commerceUser);
       customerProvider.UpdateUser(updateRequest);       
   }   
}
```

UPDATE:

The property updating code which is in `Feature.Accounts` works fine.
But I want it to be common as it has to be used in other Feature projects also. So, I'm trying to have the code in `Foundation.Accounts` which is a class library project.

This is the code in `Feature.Accounts` which works.

```
public class ProfileController : AccountProfileController
    {
        public ProfileController(Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Account.Repositories.IProfileViewRepository profileViewRepository,
            IProfileEditorRepository profileEditorRepository, IAccountManager accountManager, IStorefrontContext storefrontContext, IContext sitecoreContext,
            Repositories.IProfileViewRepository UserProfileViewRepository, IVisitorContext visitorContext)
            : base(profileViewRepository, profileEditorRepository, accountManager, storefrontContext, sitecoreContext)
        {
            this.ProfileViewRepository = UserProfileViewRepository;
            this.VisitorContext = visitorContext;                
        }
        

        public Repositories.IProfileViewRepository ProfileViewRepository { get; set; }
        
        public IVisitorContext VisitorContext { get; }

        [HttpPost]        
        public JsonResult UpdateUser(UserOfferDetails inputModel)
        {
            BaseJsonResult baseJsonResult = new BaseJsonResult(base.SitecoreContext, base.StorefrontContext);
            var profile = ProfileViewRepository.GetProfile(VisitorContext.UserName);
                if (profile != null)
                {
                    StringPropertyCollection propertyBag = new StringPropertyCollection
                     {
                        
                        { "OfferValue",inputModel.OfferAmount},
                        { "ProspectId",inputModel.ProspectId}
                    };

                    baseJsonResult = ProfileEditorRepository.SaveProfile(profile, propertyBag);

                }
                return Json(baseJsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How you have added those custom properties to the commerce side? Did you add a new component to customer or extend existing component?

Comment: Sorry no idea about commerce. But I can see those properties in biz tools. @Gaurav

Comment: So what is the name of custom property that you are talking about?

Comment: ProspectId is the name of the custom property

Comment: As I can understand this is added by someone as custom. You can add one more block in the pipeline that is being used for updateuser in Sitecore commerce side, just add it after the existing block and then in that new block get the properties and set those. For that you need to know in which component did you or your team added those custom properties.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal
There is no issue in the addition I guess, because there is another Feature specific code in controller that works. Now I want to move it to Foundation class library project to be used across other projects which is becoming a challenge. Updated the question. Can u pls chk. Thank you.

Comment: In OOTB code of ProfileEditorRepository.SaveProfile method you will find it copy the property bag in request i.e. 

UpdateUserRequest request = new UpdateUserRequest(result);
request.CopyPropertyBag(propertyBag);
serviceProviderResult = this.CustomerServiceProvider.UpdateUser(request);

similar when it call Get User then also pass the same property bag like

GetUserRequest request = new GetUserRequest(userName);
request.CopyPropertyBag(propertyBag);
GetUserResult user = this.CustomerServiceProvider.GetUser(request);

Can you please try the same?